# How to change primeNG checkbox size

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

Simple question... how I can resize `p-checkbox`? 
Without primeng I did something like
`<p-checkbox style="transform: scale(2.0)"></p-checkbox>`

But with primeng Im getting

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'transform: scale(2.0)'
    at ...
```

How to make checkbox bigger then?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by simply overwriting their `css`. First, change the size of the checkbox.
You have to set both classes below for the checkbox to be centered:

```css
    body .ui-chkbox {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
    }

    body .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
    }
```

Then you can modify the size of the checkmark:

```css
    body .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box .ui-chkbox-icon {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
```

And if needed you might also want to change the `offset` of the label:

```css
    body .ui-chkbox-label {
      margin: 0 0 0 0.8em;
    }
```

Comment: Can u provide a bit more info? I'v added those CSS, I even added `!important` everywhere but my checkbox still remains the same.

Comment: @JohnDoe Where did you add the css? It shouldn't get scoped. Make sure to add it in your global styles. You can provide me a jsfiddle and I will modify it there,

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `width` and `height` in the CSS, for example:

```css
.p-checkbox .p-checkbox-box {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}
.p-checkbox .p-checkbox-box .p-checkbox-icon {
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering on stackoverflow, please provide an explanation with your solution, so that people understand the logic behind it

Answer (score 1):

This solution might not fit all scenarios but it worked for my case.

```css
/*Increase p-checkbox size*/
:host ::ng-deep .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: ng-deep is deprecated unfortunately =(